# How to cover input field to the rest of the parent div

Tags: html, forms, width

Please see the attached image below:

[image]

div:a is the parent div which width is set to 100%, so no matter the width of the device (pc/mobile) is, it should grow to the width of the device's screen.

div:b is for the width of the input label. This div can be omitted too, but I would like to keep it and it's width is set to auto so that it can be wide according to the width of the label text.

I would like to set the width of the input field in a way so that it can cover the rest of the parent div (div:a) space.

Both div:b and div:ba are set as inline:block. I don't want to set any fixed width to any of the three divs as I want to make this layout flexible to any device screen (pc or mobile screen of different widths).

Here is the css and html code of the divs:

```
    div.a{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
    div.b {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;    
      background-color: yellow; 
    }
    div.ba {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid blue;    
      background-color: yellow; 
    }
<div class="a"><div class="b">Name:</div><div class="ba"><input type="text" /></ba></div>
```

Please note that, there will be other fields too below this input field (name) as this layout will be used to create a user input form.

Comment: Hey, could you show your code to give a solution?

Comment: @mamunmohamed done! Please review my question.

Comment: if i didn't get wrong, what you want is, extend your input field and with him div.b?

Comment: What about using flex layout. Give parent div style display:flex and div with text box flex:1. I think this will work but I'm not confident.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11270463/mamun-mohamed input field and with him div:ba, not div:b

Comment: @adp7 I want to make the layout in such way that if the screen width of the device is too low to fit input label and input field in a row, they will breakdown to two lines. Using the flex layout, as far I know, they (input label and input field) will stay in one row/line whatever the  screen width is. But if I use inline:block display properties to div, they will breakdown if screen width is too low to fit them in one line. That's the cause.